# File changes in a container could not trigger Dropbox to sync

Tags: synchronization, containers, dropbox

I have created a shared Dropbox folder in Synology NAS, which could be synced successfully with Dropbox cloud if files were created/changed in NAS regular operations. I mounted the Dropbox folder to a Docker container. The file changes from other devices (such as MAC) could be synced into the container. However, the file changes in the container could not trigger Dropbox to sync. By the way, I can see all the changes outside the container. Is there any way to solve it?
Thank you.